# Como fazer um robô pegar dados de uma tabela num website HTML

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando criar um banco de dados com históricos de ações, extraídas de um site. Abaixo segue um exemplo do que estou tentando fazer.

```
package com.gustavo.seleniumTest;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class seleniumTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/gustavo/geckodriver");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    String valor;
    driver.get("http://cotacoes.economia.uol.com.br/acao/cotacoes-historicas.html?codigo=PETR4.SA&size=200&page=1&period=");
    valor = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='odd']")).getText();
    System.out.println(valor);
}

}
```

Já consegui criar um robô com selenium para inputar valores em uma caixa de texto e apertar um botão, porém estou com dificuldade de extrair valores de uma tabela ou tag (HTML) e adicionar a uma variável ou array.

Comment: Conhece o [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)? Essa lib permite extrair dados do HTML

Answer (score 1):

Bem sempre que precisei fazer algo do tipo com tabelas, eu utilizei uma varredura completa usando o xpath abaixo (já coloquei o id da tabela que você passou no link):

```
int lineNumber = 1;
int columnIndex = 1;

String valueXpath = ".//table/tbody[@id='tblInterday']/tr[" + lineNumber + "]/td[" + columnIndex + "]"; // linha 1 x coluna 1
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(valueXpath));
String elementValue = element.getText().trim();
```

O Xpath acima vai te dar o element que contem o valor do cruzamento linha x coluna, o que precisa fazer agora é criar o código que varre toda a tabela, ou seja todas as linhas e colunas e armazenar cada valor desse.